# Nothing works When i add JSF related tags in web.xml

Tags: jsf

When i add `JSF` related tags to *web.xml* nothing is working and it gives an error. If I remove XML tags in *web.xml* then all .jsp and servlets are working fine. I also added jsf-api.jar,jsf-impl.jar,jstl.jar and standard.jar to lib folder of my project still it is not working so i added these jar files to lib folder in tomcat too but still it is not working.

Error1 with index.xhtml to url:

> XML Parsing Error: no element found
>   Location: http://www.touchegolfmart.com/index.xhtml
>   Line Number 1, Column 1:

Erro2 with out index.xhtml to url

File not found 
Firefox can't find the file at http://www.touchegolfmart.com/.

my web.xml file is

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


   <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
 <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
 </session-config>
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Context path in `server.xml` in conf folder of tomcat is:

```
 <Host name="touchegolfmart.com" appBase="/home/rathan">
      <Alias>www.touchegolfmart.com</Alias> 
      <Context path="" reloadable="true" docBase="public_html" debug="1"/>
     <!-- <Context path="/manager" debug="0" privileged="true"
          docBase="/usr/local/jakarta/tomcat/server/webapps/manager">
      </Context>-->
   </Host>
```

Folder structure is:
index.jsp
WEB-INF/classes
WEB-INF/lib
WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
WEB-INF/web.xml
WEB-lib/lib/jsf-api.jar,jsf-impl.jar,jstl.jar,standard.jar.
META-INF/context.xml

Comment: you need not only web.xml also some libraries jsf-api, jsf-impl and etc. There are a lot of examples. Look at this one http://www.roseindia.net/java/javaee6/JSF2.0SimpleExample.shtml

Comment: Sorry to mention,that i also added jsf-api.jar jsf-impl.jar,jstl.jar and standard.jar to lib folder

Comment: have faces-config.xml file? And what is your folder structure?

Comment: faces-config.xml is there and also web.xml is updated in the post

Comment: @Darka: roseindia.net is world's worst Java EE resource and is full of bad practices and misleading code examples. Please never recommend that site to starters. It would only confuse them and make the real code end up in a disaster.

Comment: @BalusC DEAL :) I am new in this too.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly put some example.
Created T folder in webapp folder.
Created file hello.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <title>JSF 2.0 Hello World</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h3>JSF 2.0 Hello World Example</h3>
        <h:form>

            <h:commandButton value="Click" action="welcome"></h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Created file welcome.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <title>JSF 2.0 Hello World</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body bgcolor="white">
        <h2>JSF 2.0 Hello World Example</h2>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

After this created folder WEB-INF in T folder and created 2 files:
web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>JSFHelloWorld</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/hello.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

</faces-config>
```

also in T/WEB-INF folder created folder lib, which has jsf-api-2.1.12.jar, jsf-impl-2.1.12.jar, jstl-1.2.jar files.

This works, but I don't used any POJO.

Comment: as my application is hosted virtual server so i placed all the files in public_html but not in the webapps folder of tomcat. for this i configured in server.xml file of tomcat/conf

Comment: I put your web.xml in my example it works but it gave me error that cant find index.xhtml file because I have hello.xhtml. So maybe you create index.xhtml there too :D just stupid prediction.

Comment: both places index.xhtml only

Comment: what do you mean both places?

Comment: I don't understand one thing, when i place all files manually in the appBase folder according to directory structure it show the error like file not found. when i place the file by using .war file in the appBase folder and extract with jar command it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing the files in the appBase folder manually, place a .war file and extract it through jar command then restarting the tomcat made my application work.